# "Entitled to" usage

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

is the sentence "what kind of jobs are you entitled to" correct? Or should it be eligible for? If both are wrong kindly suggest the appropriate word to be used.Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to tell us what meaning you want to convey. Both forms are acceptable,and grammatical  but the meaning is quite different. Have you looked up these words in a dictionary? What did they say?

Answer (score 1):

One is rarely "entitled to" a job. But one can always be "eligible (or ineligible) for" one. So the second phrase would be the appropriate one.